# VS2015 VersionControlServer

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2015, vspackage

I've had to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 and am currently having problems with my VSPackage. I need a VersionContralServer object, but everytime I debug, DTE is null.

```
 DTE2 dte = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE2));
 VersionControlExt versionControlExt = dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as VersionControlExt;
 VersionControlExplorerExt versionControlExplorerExt = versionControlExt.Explorer;
 VersionControlServer version = versionControlExplorerExt.Workspace.VersionControlServer;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which file is the snippet in?

Comment: @sprinter252 A custom controller that is invoked by the MenuItemCallback() Method.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a slight bug in your call to Package.GetGlobalService().

DTE2 dte = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(**SDTE**));

Under the hood, all the GetGlobalService call is doing is invoking an IOleServiceProvider.QueryService method, and that function requires an interface guid, and a service guid. typeof(DTE2), returns the interface guid for the DTE2 interface.

Some samples you may have seen improperly used typeof(DTE) to return the service guid. But that only works, because the DTE service guid id, and the DTE interface guid id, just happen to be the same thing. But in general, you should always use the service guid id.